# Android: Boot Broadcast not working after Reboot

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an app that uses a broadcast service to continue my pending intent after it reboots, but its not working as its supposed to. After I reboot my phone i get pop-up notification saying `MyAppsName has stopped working`. And the log I made for it does not appear.

manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.idkbro.pashchallenge">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".BaseApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />



    <receiver android:name=".AlertReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:exported="true"></service>

</application>
```

The BootReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("Xu", "Boot receiver is working");
}
```

Comment: why is uses permission declared twice in the manifest? also what is this `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` ? Is this on the HTC ?

Comment: Not I've seen to different examples that used them in 2 different areas. But I don't think that's why it's not working

Comment: Please enclose a [MCVE] example of the actual boot receiver class. You can confirm that the full package to the broadcast receiver class is `com.idkbro.pashchallenge.BootReceiver` ?

Comment: @t0mm13b Yes, com.idkbro.pashchallenge.BootReceiver is it

Comment: you need to obtain the log by logcat from bootup. plug cable in, reboot phone, issue the command `adb logcat`, it will wait until phone boots, then you can catch the logcat as to why its crashing.

Comment: @t0mm13b I know this is probably a senseless question but how do i make adb commands? Like where and how do I make them?

Comment: @t0mm13b I'm using Android studio

Comment: Nevermind I found out how to. I've found the error using the adb thank you very much

Comment: OP: Word of advice, learn to use adb, always, always check the logcat before jumping the gun and tearing off to post on SO why is the code not working when you clearly did not know how to use adb.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this in receiver class:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
   Log.i("Xu", "Boot receiver is working");
}
```

And remove permission and category intent filter from manifest reciver tag like:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm getting the same result. I get this error when i check it using the adb  `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=13157, uid=2000
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)`

Comment: Why did you advise OP to remove permission? /facepalm